# godoc pass external reference file containing documentation for code without comments

Tags: go, godoc

Instead of comments written in the code itself, is it possible to pass an external reference file to the `godoc` command containing the documentation for any uncommented code?

The requirement here is that we need to generate documentation for a codebase that does not have any proper comments within the code and we also want to keep changes to the source files to a minimum.

Any other approach which fits this requirement is welcome. No strict rule to use `godoc`

Comment: Godoc, pkg.go.dev, and the go doc command all expect to find documentation for an identifier in a comment before the identifier. You can write a tool that weaves together [parsed Go source files](https://pkg.go.dev/go/parser) and your sidecar documentation to create output that looks similar to those other tools.  You may find the [go/doc](https://pkg.go.dev/go/doc@go1.19beta1) package helpful in writing such a tool.  If possible, use the Go 1.19 version of the go/doc package.